# Is there a variable in error_page that can make this multiline nginx error config into one line

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

This is my current config

```
location =/error.css {
        root /web/belldandu/data/SYFEP;
}

location =/error.php {
        root /web/belldandu/data/SYFEP;
        include /web/belldandu/cfg.d/fastcgi;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        internal;
}

error_page 300 = /error.php?e=300&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 400 = /error.php?e=400&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 401 = /error.php?e=401&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 402 = /error.php?e=402&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 403 = /error.php?e=403&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 404 = /error.php?e=404&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 405 = /error.php?e=405&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 406 = /error.php?e=406&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 407 = /error.php?e=407&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 408 = /error.php?e=408&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 409 = /error.php?e=409&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 410 = /error.php?e=410&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 411 = /error.php?e=411&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 412 = /error.php?e=412&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 413 = /error.php?e=413&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 414 = /error.php?e=414&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 415 = /error.php?e=415&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 416 = /error.php?e=416&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 417 = /error.php?e=417&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 418 = /error.php?e=418&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
error_page 419 = /error.php?e=419&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f;
```

`$i` is a logo, `$t` is a title, and `$f` just tells SYFEP whether to display the derp message (see https://github.com/Belldandu/SYFEP/).

Currently i have to specify each error code in each error page directive (which gets annoying when your trying to make one for every error code), so i was wondering if there was a variable i could use that takes the triggered code in the list i just passed to the error_page variable and spits it back at me.

Like:
`error_page 300 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 = /error.php?e=$err_page&i=$i&t=$t&f=$f`

With `$err_page` being the code that was triggered in the list of codes before `=`

So if `300` was the triggered value then `$err_page` is `300`.

If there isn't something like this in nginx then its fine.

Comment: Have you tried `$status`?

Comment: Yes it just returns 000 oddly.